# How to get the current Testcase name in Suite Setup in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have .robot file containing Suite setup and few testcases say Test1, Test2 and Test3 . I want to run Test2. But as part of requirement I need to print the current testcase name being executed (i.e. Test2 )in suite setup. As suite setup gets executed before testcase, ${TEST_NAME} cannot be used. Is there any other way to retrieve the current testcase name? . Please help me !

Comment: "I need to print the current testcase name being executed", but in suite setup, there's no test case _being_ executed. Perhaps you want the names of test cases that are going to be executed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. yeah i need the names of the testcases that are going to be executed after suite setup is done

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to use [visitor interface](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/master/autodoc/robot.model.html#module-robot.model.visitor).

You'd create a new class where you'll iterate over all the tests:

**Libraries/Visitor.py**

```py
from robot.model.visitor import SuiteVisitor
from robot.api import logger

class Visitor(SuiteVisitor):
    def start_suite(self, suite):
        for test in suite.tests:
            logger.console("{}".format(x))
```

Then you'd run your tests with `--prerunmodifier` option where you'll specify your new class like so: `--prerunmodifier Libraries/Visitor.py`.

It'll list your test cases first and then start executing them.